# Upload of big files to data directory of postgresql 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

After 2 weeks of huge efforts to solve one postgresql problem I'm coming here as last hope.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I need to store and retrieve huge files (sizes between 1 MB to 2000 MB) to postgresql database by client desktop .NET app. I tried to use bytea, large objects and text but I have out of memory or to slow operation (7 min).

**What I need:**

I want to upload all client files to remote server  (client and server are in local network and completely visible each other) in data (postgresql/data) directory and to retreive these file from DATA directory.

**Question:**

Do you have some idea how with pure SQL or postgresql sql procedure to upload file from local machine to remote DATA directory? Do you have some idea how with pure sql or postgresql procedure(s) to download file in data directory of postgresql to local machine?

Comment: Why, out of interest? Unless you need ACID semantics for file handling, it's usually best to use an external method for file handling - WebDAV, etc.

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509747/inserting-large-object-into-postgresql-returns-53200-out-of-memory-error -- BTW transferring 2GB over network won't be fast, anyway.