# Base64 decode image save into blob database

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, base64

I am using PostgreSQL for my database and codeigniter for my php framework, I have problem when try to save blob image from base64 decode inside my foreach.

This is my code:

```
foreach($master->spesimen  as $spesimen){
                        $data_spesimen = array(
                            "indexspec" => $spesimen->indexspec,
                            "namafile" => $spesimen->nama,
                            "nama" => $spesimen->nama,
                            "imgspec" =>  base64_decode($spesimen->namafile),
                            "ref_mfpp" => $kode,
                            "useri" => $username
                        );
                        $this->kirim->specfpp($data_spesimen);
                    }
```

I got error from postgres :

> Message: pg_escape_literal(): Failed to escape

How to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just save the image on a directory and just save its path to the database?

Comment: hai @elegisandi I want save image to database, I don't want put it into file.

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288898/insert-an-image-in-postgresql-database/46314519?noredirect=1#comment93152073_46314519>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code :

```
foreach($master->spesimen  as $spesimen){
                            $data_spesimen = array(
                                "indexspec" => $spesimen->indexspec,
                                "namafile" => $spesimen->nama,
                                "nama" => $spesimen->nama,
                                "imgspec" => pg_escape_bytea(base64_decode($spesimen->namafile)),
                                "ref_mfpp" => $kode,
                                "useri" => $username
                            );
                            $this->kirim->specfpp($data_spesimen);
                        }
```

To understand more about your issue [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-bytea.php) .

Please let me know its helpful or not .

Edited answer Thanks @Denny Kurniawan for your confirmation.

Comment: I use pg_escape_bytea(base64_decode($spesimen->namafile)) and its work, thank you very much.