# Hibernate image getting truncated while saving

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. In this, I am trying to upload an image and save it in database. During that process, I tried to convert the binary data of the image to a String, and I noticed that the images binary data is truncated. Generally, if you take a image of 20-30kb, then in String one can see atleast 500-600 characters, I can only see 6-8. I am showing how I have implemented the image save and display. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong..

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductBasic {

@Column(name = "productimage")
    byte[] productimage;

 public byte[] getProductimage() {
        return productimage;
    }

    public void setProductimage(byte[] productimage) {
        this.productimage = productimage;
    }
}
```

Product service while saving. :

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class ProductBasicServiceImpl implements ProductBasicService{
    private ProductBasicDAO productBasicDAO;

    public void setProductBasicDAO(ProductBasicDAO productBasicDAO) { this.productBasicDAO = productBasicDAO; }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addProduct(User user, ProductBasic p){
       p.setProductimage(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(p.getProductimage()));
        this.productBasicDAO.addProduct(user, p);
    }
}
```

Controller for sending image as bytearray :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/{id}/image")
    public byte[] retrieveimage(@PathVariable("id")Integer id){
        ProductBasic productBasic1 = productBasicService.getProductById(id);
        if(productBasic1.getProductimage()==null){
            System.out.println("product by id image is null");
            return null;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Product by id image is not null");
            byte[] data = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(productBasic1.getProductimage());
// When I convert above byte[] to String using String builder and append data:image/png;bas64, I get String as "data:image/png;base64,B[jak23424=="
            return data;
    }
}
```

JSP :

```
 <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productimage">
                    <spring:message text="productimage"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input type="file" path="productimage" />
            </td>
        </tr>
<br>
<h3>Product List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listProducts}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Product ID</th>
            <th width="80">Product image</th>
            <th width="120">Product name</th>
            <th width="120">Product description</th>
            <th width="120">Product condition</th>
            <th width="120">Product age</th>
            <th width="120">Product EAN</th>
            <th width="120">Product ISBN</th>
            <th width="120">Product ordernumber</th>
            <th width="120">Product owners id</th>

            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${listProducts}" var="product">
            <tr>
                <td>${product.productid}</td>
                <td>${product.productimage} </td>
                <td>${product.productname}</td>
                <td>${product.productdescription}</td>
                <td>${product.productcondition}</td>
                <td>${product.productage}</td>
                <td>${product.productean}</td>
                <td>${product.productisbn}</td>
                <td>${product.ordernumber}</td>
                <td>${product.user1id}</td>
                <%--<img src="${product.productimage}" height="100" width="100"/>--%>

                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editproduct/${product.productid}' />" >Edit Product</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removeproduct/${product.productid}' />" >Delete Product</a></td>
            </tr>
            <img src="/product/${product.productid}/image" height="100" width="100"/>
            <%--<img src="${saveimage}" height="100" width="100">--%>
        </c:forEach>


    </table>
</c:if>
```

Also, when I use the below function in ServiceImpl, the saved image is just 10bytes instead of 80Kb, which is the actual image size.

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addProduct(User user, ProductBasic p){

        try {

            FileOutputStream imageoutfile = new FileOutputStream("/home/akshay/check.png");
            imageoutfile.write(p.getProductimage());
            imageoutfile.close();
            File file = new File("/home/akshay/check.png");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      p.setProductimage(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(p.getProductimage()));
        this.productBasicDAO.addProduct(user, p);
    }
```

Any pointers would be nice. i am using PostgreSQL 9.3, and in database i am saving it as bytea.

Comment: Save it as a blob instead of byte[]

Comment: Where, in Java or database, there is no Blob datatype in Postgres, only OID or byte[] or bytea

Comment: check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386030/how-to-use-blob-datatype-in-postgres

Comment: Yes, in database I have saved as bytea as mentioned in last line of my post. If that is what you are trying to tell me. Why is it getting truncated then?

Comment: try mapping it with Blob in java

Comment: Hello, I tried using @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType"), still image is truncated.