# Save image file to database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, binary

I need to save image from file to PostgreSQL database as binary. Trying to do it like this:

```
image_file = File.open("image.png", "rb") { |file| file.read }
Image.create(product_id: product_id, image: image_file)
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
string contains null byte
```

Using paperclip or similar, or converting binary to base64 are not an option.

Comment: What's the type of the column in the database? check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386030/how-to-use-blob-datatype-in-postgres

Comment: binary. Changing column type also is not an option

Comment: Which line is failing? Reading the file or saving it into the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try providing us more information, if you're able. I know there was a recent PR for Rails that fixed more superfluous bytea escaping in PostgreSQL. So definitely try updating your system to see if that helps. If it doesn't, please provide us more information if you're able.

[Here's a link to the PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17680)