# How to insert all the data in chunks into the database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, out-of-memory, gson

I am trying to insert all the data at once using the following:

```
userModel.setServiceData(gson.toJson(sortedResponse).getBytes());
```

This is giving Out of Memory for the huge data.

So I am trying to add data in chunks to the postgres database using something like:

```
byte[] chunkedMessage = {};

for (Iterator<Message> iterator = sortedResponse.iterator();  iterator.hasNext();) {
    Message message = (Message) iterator.next();
    chunkedMessage = gson.toJson(message).getBytes();
    userModel.setServiceData(chunkedMessage);
}
```

Obviously, this will end up storing the last chunk but not all chunks collectively.

I am using hibernate so thinking if there is any easy way with hibernate query or may be as easy as something in the above code.

Comment: So you have a JSON column in your PostgreSQL database and you want to insert a record with such large content inside this column that the JVM crashes?

Comment: I have a `bytea` column and when I get the response from remote API I am storing that response into this column for tracking purposes. This response can be huge which can cause OOM if stored at once.

Comment: This solution can never scale.  You get OOM error for a single user?  Good luck with two or more.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use arrays (`byte[]`), as it needs to allocate the memory for the complete data you want to insert into the database and switch to streams. Change the type of `userModel.serviceData` from `byte[]` to `java.sql.Blob`, which allows to create a new Blob instance from an InputStream or Reader:

```
Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(stream, size);
```

Comment: I will look into this solution. However, I used `bytea` after reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386030/how-to-use-blob-datatype-in-postgres

Comment: By the way, what is the datatype to store BLOB in postgres?