# How to save large text into table in PostgreSQL (using Java)

Tags: java, blob, oid, large-data

I have a large text and I want to save them to A column in B Table using PostgreSQL. "A" column type is OID, i think that if using OID datatype I can save large text. Is it exactly? Without OID, have any datatype which I can save large text? I also get this large text to display in my app. What should I do? Give me some advice.
Thank for your kindless,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `OID` is an [Object Identifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-oid.html). It is designed to be used as keys.

There is a [blob type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html). I believe you will wish to investigate using a blob. Technically, a blob is a `bytea` type, as indicated by the documentation. This [SO question: how to use Blob datatype in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386030/how-to-use-blob-datatype-in-postgres) provides some additional information.

If a blob does not fit your exact needs (it is binary data, but it depends on exactly what constitutes the large text; in my experience, many who believe they have text actually have some binary data), there is also a [text type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html) as well.

You may also wish to [look at this SO question about text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying).

Comment: I can not see Blob type. When I set Blob type in my code, it automatic convert to OID type.

Comment: @user2678221, it is `bytea` for the actual type, as noted in the link. I apologize for the slight confusion on the terminology. You may wish to look at [how to use Blob datatype in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386030/how-to-use-blob-datatype-in-postgres) as well.

Comment: oh yeah. I used byte[] as datatype and it automatic sets 'A' column datatype as bytea. Now I am trying to read data from bytea