# Can I store a Word document in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We maintain our data in a PostgreSQL database, and keep the relevant documentation in the form of Word (TM) files.

Now a peculiar sentence in the description of the project states that the documentation should be stored 'together with the data, in the data base.'

My question: Can I store a Word document in a PostgreSQL database?

It's okay if I have to zip it first, maybe even convert to .pdf, or similar tricks. But it should of cause be possible to retrieve the data out again, and re-create the document we put in.

Comment: You can store this using a binary data type:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html.

Comment: It is not possible to search for text inside a Word doc when it is stored in the database.

Comment: You can store anything you want in PostgreSQL. Whether it's a good idea, on the other hand, is an entirely different question.

Comment: Duplicate of [how to use Blob datatype in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386030/how-to-use-blob-datatype-in-postgres)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can!

A column of type `bytea` can hold up to 1 GB of binary data.

Considering the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_document
(
    id BIGINT, 
    info TEXT, 
    doc BYTEA, 
    CONSTRAINT pk_tbl_document PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

Use `decode()` function to store a document file from its `base64` representation:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_document ( id, info, doc ) VALUES ( 1, 'Personal Resume', decode( 'TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0u', 'base64')::bytea  );
```

Use `encode()` function to retrieve back the document in its `base64` representation:

```
SELECT info, encode( doc, 'base64' ) FROM tbl_document WHERE id = 1;
```

Use `pg_read_file()` function to read binary files directly into the database:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_document ( id, info, doc ) VALUES ( 2, 'Daily Report', pg_read_file('report.doc')::bytea );
```

Hope It Helps!

Comment: can I ask a question please. what does this mean "TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0u"?

Comment: @Mr.Aw Means "Lorem ipsum." in base64 encoding.