# Python Insert pickle file/object in postgres DB

Tags: python, postgresql, insert, pickle, bytea

I need to insert my ml_model.pkl file/object in Postgres DB bytea column.

Is it possible to insert any files in Postgres DB bytea column?

Comment: Use blobs - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386030/how-to-use-blob-datatype-in-postgres. Hope this is helpful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.