# Saving product images and translation in JSONB column or another table

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, adonis.js

I’m working on an e-commerce store that is multi-lang and I’m using Node.js and PostgreSQL.

I’m confused if I should store the product images in a separate table or in a JSONB column in database?

The same thing for the translation, the product may have different titles for every language so which one is better ? to store them in a separate table too, or in JSONB column?

**Edit 1:**
By saving images in the database I mean the path of the image in Amazon S3 or something like this not the image itself

**Edit 2:**
Let's say I have a logo, thumbnail, and banner for the product also the product has multiple images for the carousel, which one is better, store them in JSONB column or multiple varchar columns or a separate table?

Comment: You may place the product images in a `bytea` or Base64-encoded `text` column, not JSONB. They will be [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/storage-toast.html)-ed.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question because I was asking if I should save the image path in separate table or in a json column, not the image itself

Answer (score 1):

I'm not marking this question as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500/storing-images-in-postgresql) just because it includes also a question about how to store internationalization data.

#### I’m confused if I should store the product images in a separate table or in a JSONB column in database?

I would avoid saving images in a database. A better approach would be using file system or cloud storage like Amazon S3; then you could save a filesystem path or cloud URL in a `VARCHAR` column to have a reference to the image file.

If you still want to save images in PostgreSQL, if for each product you only have one image, I don't see the a reason to use a separate table. You can use bytea or blobs. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500/storing-images-in-postgresql) for more details.

#### The same thing for the translation, the product may have different titles for every language so which one is better ? to store them in a separate table too, or in JSONB column?

I see two possible approach:

1. Storing titles in one nullable column for each supported language. If you plan to add languages in the future, you have to handle it with database migrations. Also, if you have more text data like product descriptions that should be supported for all languages, you will need not only the `en_tile`, `fr_title`, `es_title` ... columns but also the `en_description`, `fr_description`, `es_description` ... as well.
2. Using `JSONB` (or even better `JSON`) datatype. You can store all internazionalized data in a single JSON column, with more flexibility if the `JSON` structure changes. I would use `JSON` instead of `JSONB` because it's faster and requires less space on disk. `JSONB` should be used if you intend to index JSON properties and to query with conditions on them. I don't think this is the case. [Here](https://www.educba.com/postgresql-json-vs-jsonnb/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql) you can read more on JSON vs JSONB in postgres

I would go for option 2.

#### EDIT 1

As Frank Heikens told in comments, `JSONB` is generally adviced over `JSON` from [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html).
Benchmarks could help you to understand better if JSON or JSONB is the best choice for you.
I've found a benchmark [here](https://github.com/evanj/pg-benchmarks). Results here shows better performance on `JSONB` over `JSON`. This is strange to me to be honest and if I will have time I will do some more depth test.
Anyway, for your situation, `JSONB` should just be fine as JSON is.

Comment: Why using the JSON datatype when even the manual advises the usage of JSONB? "In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as jsonb, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy assumptions about ordering of object keys.". https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Comment: again, because the JSON type Is more efficient. If you don't Need indexing in the column, using JSONB Will Just requires more space and time. For small objects this difference Is negible. But when objects grows...

Comment: I updated the question, I was asking to save the image path, not the image itself

Comment: For the translation, I tried both options but I think option 2 will be better to store them all in one json column, not a separate table or multiple columns 

Comment: @radar155: the manual tells me jsonb is the most efficient data type, not json because that’s just synthetic sugar for text

Comment: @FrankHeikens what do you mean with efficient? The PostgreSQL documentation tells that jsonb should be used in most cases because it assumes that if you store a JSON in a postgres database, you are then going to perform queries where you want to filter for a JSON property; or maybe you want to select only a JSON property in your query output. For this kind of usage, JSONB is more efficient than JSON. But if you only plan to store and retrieve the entire JSON data, without any operation on it, JSON should be the way to go.

Comment: @radar155: you’re saying the manual is wrong, because it states pretty clear that jsonb is the way to go: In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as jsonb

Comment: I'm not saiyng the manuale Is wrong at all. It dependa on use cases. I Will edit my answer with benchmarks to prove It. In the past I already switched from JSONB to  JSON to improve performance of a highly used postgresql table

Comment: Ok I don't have the possibility to write the benchmark by myself now. But googling i've found [this](https://github.com/evanj/pg-benchmarks). From this benchmarks, it looks JSONB are faster than JSON; based on my experience, this results are strange, but in next days I will try to make new benchmarks by myself. I already did in the past ai I told you, with a great performance improvement passing from JSONB to JSON (as indexing and json operations were not required). For now, I'll edit my response suggesting only JSONB. I will do more benchmark and if needed I will edit it again.